# Why am I getting 500 server error when making post request with axios?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

Upon the user submitting which picture of their choosing, I'd like to know why it won't get sent to the database upon form submission.  I believe my Models and Controller are a bit off, namely in the `PostPicturesController.php` file where my method chaining might be off.  How can I fix this and make user chosen file get sent to the database upon form submission.

error in console I'm getting is:

```
POST http://my_website.test/home 500 (Internal Server Error)
Here's the error Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

error I'm getting in the logs:

```
[2019-09-15 17:21:20] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::postPictures() 
{"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): 
Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsTo::postPictures()
```

Here's `PostPicturesController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\PostPictures;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostPicturesController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, PostPictures $postPicture) {
        $uploadPic = $request->user()->postPictures()->get();
        return response()->json($postPicture->with('user')->find($uploadPic->id));
    }
}
```

Here's `PostPictures.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostPictures extends Model {
//    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here's `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function postPictures() {
        return $this->hasMany(PostPictures::class);
    }
}
```

Here's my post request in react.js file using axios:

```
submission() {
    let picUrl = this.state.previewImgURL;

    axios.post(`/home`, picUrl)
        .then((response) => console.log("Here's the response " + response))
        .catch(error => console.log("Here's the error " + error));
 }
```

Comment: Are you logged in to the application?

Comment: @ItzhakAvraham yeah i am

Comment: You aren't doing any file upload logic in your controller. The `$uploadPic` line is where the error is coming from, but that line is attempting to fetch existing data from the database. [Laravel documentation on uploading files.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#files)

Answer (score 0):

use this [software](https://www.getpostman.com/) for debug api link and check what line or file getting error and post here

Comment: woops, didn't add the error I'm getting in the logs... I've posted it in my original post